# How to save all objects' position and rotation?

Tags: transforms

I am using blender to organize my home furniture, with different layout scenarios.
How can I save multiple layouts for the furniture (Object) position and rotation?

Comment: Hello and welcome. You could try with [COLLECTIONS](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/introduction.html)

Comment: Hello. Please add more details on what you actually want. Attach some screenshots.

Comment: You could make an 'animation'. Keyframe the positions and locations at different (maybe sequential) frames, to stash them for viewing.

Comment: thank you for the helps.
I just using blender to plan my apartment furniture layout.
Collection seems need to duplicate objects to work.
The key-frame solution can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each arrangement of your furniture, <kbd>I</kbd> keyframe the location and rotation of the items, at a given frame. Then you can jump to that frame to restore the arrangement.